# `-bash: rbenv: command not found` comes up every time I open a terminal on window. How do I fix this?

Tags: rbenv

I have this `bash: rbenv: command not found` thing always coming up on my terminal whenever I open it and they appear four times as shown below.

I am using windows, please, how do I fix this? All solutions I have researched are tailored toward MacOs.

```
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: rbenv: command not found
bash: rbenv: command not found
```

Comment: `bash` is a Unix thing. If you're on Windows, why is it talking about bash? What are you using to run bash? Perhaps Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using windows, please, how do I fix this? All solutions I have researched are tailored toward MacOs.

The error is coming from `bash`, a Unix shell. It's unclear how that's running on Windows (perhaps Windows Subsystem for Linux?) but the MacOS (really Unix) instructions should work.

Presumably you installed [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) in this Unix on Windows environment at some point and now it's gone. If you want it back, [install it again](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv).

If you want it gone, [follow the uninstall instructions](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv). `rbenv` will add a line `rbenv init` to your shell startup configuration files. In bash, look at your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files in your home directory and remove anything to do with `rbenv`.

If you don't know how to use bash, see [Introduction to Bash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/bash-introduction/) for more.

Comment: I think that was what happened. I remember deleting it some time ago. I have installed it again following the instructions on the link you sent but I am still having the same.

Comment: @DennisAkagha We'd need to know more about your Unix on Windows environment to help more. This might be a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).